# cannot find module chai though it exists in node modules folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, chai, node-modules

I tried install chai using the following command.

```
 npm install --save-dev chai
```

Then I ran my unit test class with the following imports.

```
import {assert} from 'chai';
import {expect} from 'chai';
```

It throws the below errors.

```
test\main\MessageBroker.spec.ts(3,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.
[05:38:45] [Typescript] TypeScript error: test\main\MessageBroker.spec.ts(3,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.
test\main\MessageBroker.spec.ts(4,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.
[05:38:45] [Typescript] TypeScript error: test\main\MessageBroker.spec.ts(4,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'
```

What am I doing wrong here? I can see chai folder inside node_modules folder as well.

When I say var chai = require('chai'); it works! why doesn't import work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not installed a typing for chai, that is I haven't referred chai from DefinitelyTyped but have installed it as a node module. Therefore I had to call it using a require statement in my typescript code.

```
 var chai = require('chai');
```

Comment: Why would one use `require` in a TypeScript project especially when a the type is defined for `chai`?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using something like Babel behind the scenes to transpile to ES5.

If that is the case it's actually executing `require` over Node, CommonJS style.

This way you may succeed if you just append the path with `./` just like we do in CommonJS.

Please give it a try, I hope this fix your issue:

```
import {assert} from './chai';
import {expect} from './chai';
```

Comment: I'm using this generator https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-typescript-npm-bower. Its targeting ES5. But putting ./ didn't help. It still says it can't find the module. I cannot change the target to ES6. So any other workarounds?

Comment: If it's targeting ES5 then I believe you should not try to use the syntax `import {assert} from 'chai'` because that is ES6 syntax, not ES5. I would then just go ahead and go with `var chai = require('chai');` since that is valid ES5 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error can be actually resoved by installing the types. It is strange, but it worked for me. Give it a try:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/chai
```